# same area and perimeter

Tags: contest-math, triangles, area

> The perimeter and the area of a given triangle have the same numerical value when measured via a certain unit of measure. If the lengths of the three altitudes of the triangle are p, q, and r, what is the numerical value of $1/q + 1/p + 1/r$?

So first I set up the three sides' lengths as $a, b, c$ respectively, so that the perimeter and area both would be $a+b+c$. but the area is also equal to $ap/2 + bq/2 + cr/2 = a+b+c$, which leads to $ap + bq+cr = 2a + 2b + 2c$. However, $1/q + 1/p + 1/r = (qr + pr + pq)/(pqr)$, which doesn't seem to help much. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{a}{2A}+\frac{b}{2A}+\frac{c}{2A}=\frac{P}{2A}$$
where $a,b,c$ are the sides of the triangle, $A$ is the area and $P$ is the perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

$$A = \frac{ap}{2}= \frac{bq}{2}= \frac{cr}{2}=a+b+c.$$
$$\frac{ap}{2}=a+b+c$$
$$p=\frac{2(a+b+c)}{a}$$
Similarly,
$$q=\frac{2(a+b+c)}{b}$$
$$r=\frac{2(a+b+c)}{c}$$
Now
$$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{a}{2(a+b+c)}+\frac{b}{2(a+b+c)}+\frac{c}{2(a+b+c)}$$$$$$
$$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{a+b+c}{2(a+b+c)}$$$$$$$$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2(a+b+c)=pa.$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{p}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{2(a+b+c)}=\frac{1}{2}$$